# How to set variable name with "i" in for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

results is some location data with latitude & longitude

```
for(i=0; i<results.length ; i++ ){
  var (marker + i) = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: results[i].geometry.location,
    map: map
  });

  var (infowindow + i)= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "test" + i
  });

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, 'click', function() {
    (infowindow + i).open(map,marker);
  }); 
}
```

Above is my code but not working.

I am using google map api and would like to add info windows for each marker.
How to set my variable name so I can have different infowindow when click each marker?

for example, when I click marker1 it will have info window with "test1" and click on marker2 it will show "test2"...etc.

Comment: `infowindow` variable seems to be not declarated. If you don't have any declaration before this code, this should not work.

Comment: Seems you want arrays like `marker[i]` and `infowindow[i]`. And you should declare them outside the for loop like `var marker = []; var infowindow = [];`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a variable like `var (marker + i)`, but you can declare an array or an object, and use their `index/key` to achieve what you expect.

Another issue is

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow[i].open(map,marker);
});
```

The `i` will all reference to the last loop's `i`, which would be `results.length`, you may use an IIFE to let a function store the correct `infowindow[i]` for you. You can take a look of the following snippet.

```js
var vals = [];
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  vals[i] = i;
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Directly add event: i is now' + i + ', vals[i] is now' + vals[i]);
  });
  
  (function(idx) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('Use IIFE: i is now' + idx + ', vals[i] is now' + vals[i]);
    });
  }(i));

}
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

So your code could be write as

```
// Declare variables that is about to use in for loop.
var i;
var marker = [];
var infowindow = []; 
for(i = 0; i < results.length ; i++) {
  marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: results[i].geometry.location,
    map: map
  });

  infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "test" + i
  });

  // This IIFE will do what in the function's body, 
  // as infowindow[i] is now passed as a param named `infowindow`,
  // we can ensure the event's target infowindow will be affect by the for-loop's i.
  (function(infowindow) {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }); 
  }(infowindow[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to declare and use an array called `marker`, so that you can use the syntax `marker[i]` to access the i-th element, looks like this:

```
var marker = [];
// create other arrays here, the same way as the line above
for(i=0; i<results.length ; i++ ){
  marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: results[i].geometry.location,
     map: map
   });
  // put more code here to add data to the other arrays
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use array instead, you can add a custom parameter to the marker to catch your info like this:

```
var markers = [];
var info = [];
for(i=0; i<results.length ; i++ ){
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: results[i].geometry.location,
      map: map,
      infoIndex: i,
    }));

    info.push(new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "test" + i,
    }));

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, 'click', function() {
      info[marker.infoIndex].open(map,marker);
    }); 
}
```

with your prev logic ( quite apart that var declaration can't be done ) your event will fire every time with the last i value